Find the side size of the square in the figure below
In the plane figure below, we have a parallelogram $ABCD$ and three squares, two of which have side measurements equal to the sides of the parallelogram and the largest of which has side measurements equal to the longest diagonal of the parallelogram. Knowing that the side of the shaded square measures 1 cm, calculate the numerical value of the area of ​​the largest square, if $P$, $A$ and $C$ are collinear.
(Answer:$3$)

This is what I got
$∠DAB=∠DCB⟹90o+∠CAB=∠BCA+∠CAD∠BAC=∠CAD∴∠BCA=90o$
$△DAC≅△BCA⟹BC=1$

Could data be missing or would a solution be possible?

The conditions provided are not sufficient to uniquely determine the area of the largest square.  To see why, fix the smallest square (in your diagram, $ADNP$).  Extend $\overline{PA}$ and choose an arbitrary point $C$ on this line.  Construct $\overline{BC} \parallel \overline{AD}$ and choose $B$ on the opposite side of $\overline{AC}$ as $D$, such that $BC = AD = 1$.  Then $ABCD$ is a parallelogram since $\triangle ADC \cong \triangle CBA$.  But since the choice of $C$ is arbitrary, we can make the square $BEFD$ as large as we please.

+1. Agreed, I came to the same conclusion.

THanks for explanation
